# How can I draw a network with labelled vertices and edges?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-styles

I would like to draw the graph in the picture below using LaTeX, I want it to be in nice better shape.
1.) The position of the edge labels I would like to center it in middle over or below the edge as in the picture and does not conflict the other labels.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}\setlength\extrarowheight{7pt}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1cm]
%\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle];
    %\node[shape=circle,draw=black, scale=0.7,line width=1.5pt] (v0) at (0,0) {$\textbf{0}$}; 
\path (0:0cm) node[draw,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (v0) {$a1$};
\path (20:2cm) node[draw,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (v1) {$a2$};
\path (60:2cm) node[draw,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (v2) {$a3$};
\path (120:2cm) node[draw,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (v5) {$a4$};
\path (160:2cm) node[draw,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (v6) {$a5$};
\path (70:4cm) node[draw,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (v11) {$a6$};
\path (50:4cm) node[draw,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (v12) {$a7$};
\path (110:4cm) node[draw,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (v13) {$a8$};
\path (130:4cm) node[draw,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (v14) {$a9$};
%\path (90:1.9cm) node[draw=none,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (a10) ;
\path (-80:2cm) node[draw,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (v16) {$a11$};
\path (-120:2cm) node[draw,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (v17) {$a12$};
\path (-110:4cm) node[draw,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (v18){$a13$};
\path (-130:4cm) node[draw,shape=circle, scale=0.7,thick] (v19) {$a14$};
\path [thick](v0) edge[black] node[below] {\color{black}  $a15$} (v1);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\path [thick](v1) edge[black] node[above,right] {\color{black} \small $n1$} (v2);
\path [thick](v2) edge[black] node[left] {\color{black} \small $n2$} (v0);
\path [thick](v0) edge[black] node[left] {\color{black} \small $n3$} (v5);
\path [thick](v5) edge[black] node[left] {\color{black} {\small $n4$}} (v6);
\path [thick](v6) edge[black] node[below] {\color{black} \small $n5$} (v0);
\path [thick](v2) edge[black] node[left] {\color{black} \small $n6$} (v11);
\path [thick](v2) edge[black] node[below] {\color{black} {\small $n7$}} (v12);
\path [thick](v11) edge[black] node[below left] {\color{black} \small  $n8$} (v12);
%\draw
%(v11) -- (v12) node[pos=.5,above=1mm right=1mm] {$n9$}
\path [thick](v5) edge[black] node[right] {\color{black} \small $n10$} (v13);
\path [thick](v5) edge[black] node[below left] {\color{black} \small $n11$} (v14);
\path [thick](v13) edge[black] node[above left] {\color{black} \small $n12$} (v14);
\path [thick](v0) edge[black] node[right] {\color{black} \small $n13$} (v16);
\path [thick](v0) edge[black] node[left] {\color{black} \small $x$} (v17);
\path [thick](v16) edge[black] node[below] {\color{black} \small $y$} (v17);
\path [thick](v17) edge[black] node[right] {\color{black} \small $z$} (v18);
\path [thick](v17) edge[black] node[left] {\color{black} \small $w$} (v19);
\path [thick](v18) edge[black] node[below] {\color{black} \small $f$} (v19);
\end{tikzpicture}

          \end{minipage}
\quad
        %\end{center}
    %   \end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\begin{figure}[H]
%\begin{center}\setlength\extrarowheight{7pt}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.7cm, y=1cm]
    %First place the vertices. Note the names correspond to the labels.
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black, scale=0.7,thick] (v0) at (0,0) {$0g$}; 
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black, scale=0.7,thick] (v8) at (42:3) {$t$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black, scale=0.7,thick] (v9) at (105:2.8) {$y$} ;
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black, scale=0.7,thick] (v11) at (155:3) {$tt$} ;
\node[shape=circle,draw=black, scale=0.7,thick] (v6) at (205:3) {$e$} ;
\node[shape=circle,draw=black, scale=0.7,thick] (v2) at (227:4) {$w$} ;
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black, scale=0.7,thick] (v5) at (262:2) {$q$} ;

    \foreach \x/\y/\lab in {0/8/left,0/7/below,0/9/right,0/11/below left,0/5/right,0/6/above left,5/2/below right,6/2/left,9/11/above left,7/8/above right}
    \draw[thick] (v\x)--node[above, \lab] {\pgfmathparse{int(abs(\x-\y))}{{\pgfmathresult}}} (v\y);
    %\draw[thick] (v\x)--node[above, \lab, text=blue] {\pgfmathparse{int(abs(\x-\y))}{\pgfmathresult}} (v\y);  
    \end{tikzpicture}

          \end{minipage}
    
        \end{center}
        \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, it's nice of you to ask, but it seems that you have been pleased several times to behave accordingly to this place rules, and still don't. Please be kind to make the first step(s). https://tex.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: I added my latex trials

Comment: You already ask similar question and got good answers on them. Why you not use one of them in draw your new not so different images? BTW, so far you not accept any of gotten answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draw a graph with a common vertex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544140/draw-a-graph-with-a-common-vertex)

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'll try again, but you'll have to finish it...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{vnode/.style={draw,thick,circle,minimum width=1cm,inner sep=0pt}};
        \def\dist{3}
        
        % Nodes
        
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={vnode}]
            \node (a1) {$a_1$};
            \foreach \i [count=\ang from 2] in {2,3,11,10,9,6}
                {
                \path (a1) --++ (60*\ang:\dist) node (a\i) {$a_{\i}$};
                }
                
            \foreach \i [count=\ang] in {5,4}
                {
                \path (a2) --++ (30+60*\ang:\dist) node (a\i) {$a_{\i}$};
                }
                
            \foreach \i [count=\ang from 0] in {8,7}
                {
                \path (a6) --++ (30+60*\ang:\dist) node (a\i) {$a_{\i}$};
                }
                
            \foreach \i [count=\ang from 0] in {12,13}
                {
                \path (a11) --++ (210+60*\ang:\dist) node (a\i) {$a_{\i}$};
                }
        \end{scope}
        
        % Paths
        
        \path%[every node/.style={sloped}]
            (a1)    edge node[left] {N6} (a2)
                    edge node[above] {N5} (a3)
                    edge node[left] {N7} (a11)
                    edge node[right] {N12} (a10)
                    edge node[above] {N13} (a9)
                    edge node[right] {N14} (a6)
            (a2)    edge node[right] {N3} (a5)
                    edge node[below left] {N2} (a4)
            (a4)    edge node[above left] {N1} (a5)
            
            % To be continued...
        ;

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: not finished]

Remember it's only one straightforward approach to let you learn from it. Be kind and do your part, now ;)